# ASP.NET MVC: Get URLs to RouteTable Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'd like to enumerate all the routes in my application, and get the URLs to them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try something like this:

```
List<string> ApplicationRoutes = new List<string>();

foreach (Route r in RouteTable.Routes)
    ApplicationRoutes.Add(r.Url);
```

And just to clarify, this will simply give you the URL pattern, not the actual URL.

Comment: It's the casting to Route that does it.  `var r in RouteTable.Routes` doesn't have access to .Url because it come out as a RouteBase.  Yet another testament to the pitfalls of implicit casting.

Answer (score 0):

Routes contain URL-PATTERNS, not URLs. So, info that you're looking for is simply not there.

Answer (score 0):

Phil Haack put together a MVC Route Debugger that might be of use to you.  You incorporate it into the DEBUG version of your application and it will display all routes and what route the current request maps to.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx