# Iteration Through Routes Mapped to RouteTable.Routes via MapHttpRoute - MVC4 Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have mapped a multitude of routes to my MVC4 project as follows:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // API routing
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SomeApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Default controller mapping for non-web api views (testing)
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        //etc.
    }
```

This works just as planned, and my routes are properly registered. However, later on within my views, I am wanting to only display the api for certain routes, as well as allow the user to select which routes to display the api for. To do this, I need to be able to iterate through the routes that I added and use their string values to filter out the routes I want to use (example below shows how I would set a list to display only api methods using the `api/{controller}/{id}` route).

```
var list = group.Where(g => (g.Route.RouteTemplate == "api/{controller}/{id}"));
```

I am unsure exactly how to go about this. I stumbled across [this tidbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900475/asp-net-mvc-get-urls-to-routetable-routes), but the data within `RouteTable.Routes` can not be iterated via a `Route` type, but rather only by a `RouteBase` type (even though `Route` extends this class), which has no method that I can see to retrieve the routing string, `RouteTemplate`.

So, it looks like my main conundrum is figuring out how to iterate through `RouteTable.Routes` and store the HttpRoutes I mapped. Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this statement? `I am wanting to only display the api for certain routes, as well as allow the user to select which routes to display the api for`. If you are looking to iterate only through Web API route collection, you could do something like `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes` to get `HttpRouteCollection`. This collection would have all your api routes.

Comment: KiranChalla: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for the quick fix. For others to use as reference, this is the code that can be used to iterate (and display in Razor) the registered API Routes:
`@{var routes = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes;}  
@foreach (var r in routes)  
{  
 @r.RouteTemplate<br />  
}`

Comment: Cool..let me add an answer with this.

Comment: Sounds great. You could incorporate my sample code into it, if you'd like. The formatting in my comment above looks terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to iterate only through Web API route collection, you could do something like `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes` to get `HttpRouteCollection`. This collection would have all your api routes.